# How to add commas and after every 7 entries go to a new line in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, csv

So, here's the deal. I have a program to read in a .CSV file or notepad file.

In the .CSV file it will be 7 items in a row on the spreadsheet then go to the next row and again 7 items. 20 rows in total.

Or, it will be in a notepad file read

```
xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx
```

Then it will go so on.

It will get read into my program in a listbox and from there you can add or delete records. It also sorts them all vertically in the listbox and removes the commas.

The problem comes when saving. Here is my code for my savefile dialog:

```
    Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Data Files|*.csv;*.txt;*"
    Dim SaveFile As String
    Dim ItemsSaved As Integer
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    SaveFile = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    ItemsSaved = 0
    If SaveFile <> "" Then
        Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText(SaveFile)
        ItemsSaved = DataAssignmentBox.Items.Count
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To DataAssignmentBox.Items.Count - 1
            Dim items As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            For Each currentItem As Object In Me.DataAssignmentBox.Items
                items.Append(currentItem.ToString())
                items.Append(",")
            Next
            sw.WriteLine(DataAssignmentBox.Items.Item(i))
        Next
        sw.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Now, the problem comes when I look at the saved file. In a notepad it will be saved like so:

```
xxxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxx
```

And so on for all of the items. But, I want it to go back to the original form of comma seperated and 7 to a line then new line, I cannot get the append to work nor do I know how to start the next line. The VbCr I can't figure out. I do not know where I am going wrong and it is driving me crazy. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}...", DataAssignmentBox.Items(0), DataAssignmentBox.Items(1), DataAssignmentBox.Items(2) ...`

Comment: [Stop writing CSV parsers](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble). It is harder than you think, and there are plenty of already-working [CVS parsers](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) ready to drop into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Dim items As String
For i = 0 To DataAssignmentBox.Items.Count - 1
'Your loop
    For Each currentItem As Object In Me.DataAssignmentBox.Items

        items = items + (currentItem.ToString() + ",")
    Next
    sw.WriteLine(items)
Next
```